# Import some json data

Tags: json, r, import, jsonlite

I would like to import json data in R.
I know some discussions are already posted about this subject, but unfortunately I don't have the result I want with these codes or they have many errors with my file.

I would like to import this:
https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/streams/symbol/AAPL.json
in R.

I tried to do that:

```
AAPLapi <-  'https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/streams/symbol/AAPL.json'

AAPLapi <- fromJSON(AAPLapi)

AAPLapi <- lapply(AAPLapi, function(x) {
  x[sapply(x, is.null)] <- NA
  unlist(x)
})

table=do.call("rbind", AAPLapi)
View(table)
```

But it's having an error at the line `table=do.call`....... 
Last week I don't know why but the line worked, but I had a table very weird and it was wrong.

Could you help me please?

Comment: Please include the output of `sessionInfo()` in your question (or at least include your OS, and the versions of the curl and jsonlite packages you're using).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try package `jsonlite` maybe it will help you :

```
library("jsonlite")
your_json <- stream_in(url("https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/streams/symbol/AAPL.json"))
str(your_json, max.level = 2)
View(your_json$messages)
```

If your json is in a `.txt` file you can do :

```
download.file(url = "https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/streams/symbol/AAPL.json", destfile = "AAPL.txt")
your_json <- stream_in(file("AAPL.txt"))
```

Comment: My .txt file is on my computer, instead of "APPL.txt" what do I have to write please? I try with the emplacement of the file on my computer : "C:\\....\\file.txt" but it does not work

Comment: Are you sure for the path ? What's the name of your file ? Try the code above.

Comment: Yes I am sure of the path. It's "test1.txt" It's not data from an URL it's a file that I have on my computer from a test that I did before to get some tweets from an api.

Comment: json.text <- stream_in(file("C:/..../test1.txt"))
opening file input connection.
Found 5 lines...
Error in parse_string(txt, bigint_as_char) : 
  parse error: trailing garbage
          ","companyname":"3M Company"},{"datetime":"2015-07-07 09:10:
                     (right here) ------^
In addition: Warning message:
In readLines(con, n = pagesize, encoding = "UTF-8") :
  incomplete final line found on 'C:/.../test1.txt'
closing file input connection.

Comment: Probably a malformation of the json itself. With `download.file(url = "https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/streams/symbol/AAPL.json", destfile = "AAPL.txt")` I have no problem.

Comment: Yes it is also working for me this way, but I don't want to import this file, I want to import the one on my computer, "test1"!! It's another one from a test I made weeks ago! It's not about appl, it's another one...

{"datetime":"2015-07-08 09:10:00","subject":"MMM","sscore":"-0.2280","smean":"0.2593","svscore":"-0.2795","sdispersion":"0.375","svolume":"8","sbuzz":"0.6026","lastclose":"155.430000000","companyname":"3M Company"},{"datetime......... etc

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
library(curl)
library(jsonlite)
AAPLapi <- 'https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/streams/symbol/AAPL.json'
df=stream_in(curl(AAPLapi))
```

Comment: df=stream_in(curl(AAPLapi))
opening curl input connection.
Found 1 lines...
binding pages together (no custom handler).
closing curl input connection.
Warning message:
In readLines(con, n = pagesize, encoding = "UTF-8") :
  incomplete final line found on 'https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/streams/symbol/AAPL.json'

Comment: see df to check the data

Comment: Yes thank you, I found my data with View(df$messages) thank you very much